# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, google-console-developer

My native android app gets rejected from the google play console due to the 64-bit requirement, even though it contains 64bit libraries.

- I followed the steps on https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit by checking there are x86_64 and arm64_v8a folders which contain all the .so files.
- I tested installing the app using `adb install --abi arm64-v8a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk` which installed successfully and the app runs fine on my Pixel3a.
- I do not use `ndk.abiFilters` in my gradle file (which defaults to all architectures).
- `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` is `28`
- Screenshot of the libraries in my generated apk:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWNFO.jpg. I believe this are all from the Fresco library. Extract from my gradle file:

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.13.0'
```

- I am not using the androidX support libraries so cannot go higher than that version of fresco.

Here is the error I get when trying to upload to the console

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
>   The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 74.

I have seen a few other posts about this error but they are normally related to ReactNative or Expo, whereas my app is full native android.

Anyone got any idea on what I'm doing wrong, or how the google console checks if an app is 64bit ready?
Thanks

Comment: analyze an APK **Build>Analyze APK** and will get the reason

Comment: I did that and posted the screenshot of my libs folder. Can I get any more info out of the APK analyzer?

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to make an entry of those libs folders name in app gradle

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. How did you fix this?